# Why would a Java function block on the monitor of Reference$Lock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm looking into a program that hits some sort of concurrency bottleneck when it goes from 4 to 8 threads. Using Yourkit, I've watched the monitor profile, and it tells me that the threads are ending up blocked on the monitor of java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock while in a function which is not synchronized and not calling anything synchronized.

There are zero, no, zilch, references to the class Reference.Lock or Reference in my code. Not in the function at the top of the stack when the profiler shows the threads blocked, and not anywhere else. There are, in fact, no references to any of the subclasses of Reference in any of my code at all. So this question is about the internal working of the JVM, not about my code. Presumably, behind my back, `new char[100]` gets into this pickle, and I'm asking about how and why.

I'm using java 1.6.0_26 on a Linux box with 16 cores, otherwise relatively idle.

The function in at the top of the backtrace does allocate.

Comment: Are you using a WeakHashMap?

Comment: Nope I am not using a WeakHashMap.

Comment: Please show us the code in question. My crystal ball seems to be malfunctioning again.

Comment: The question is answerable as written. "Under what circumstances does a Java program hold a lock on Reference$Lock". I'm not asking you to remote-profile my application, I'm asking a question about the role of that class.

Comment: THe question is answerable as written by the author of the class. Anyone else is just speculating based on the source code, which you could look at yourself just as easily.